# How do i perform mousehover on multiple values which can be differentiate just by style attribute's values such as 'top' and 'left'

Tags: selenium

Here is image...[![ https://i.stack.imgur.com/651dH.png

In above Image 2 widgets are there.
1.   which gives MG, MP, Assigned etc(left-hand panel)
2.  Right panel(16.9%, 13.1% etc).And these all values gives tooltip.
Step 1:
I have to click one of the option from left-hand-side, in a screenshot its showing MG, MP, Assigned etc. All these options can be differentiate only with style attributes(top and left) and that are into range such as top:235-247px, left:65-72px(for first option)
The code is as below:

```
<div class="tab-tooltip tab-widget tab-tooltipBR" style="user-select: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; top: 247px; left: 71px;">
  <div class="tab-tooltipContainer">
    <div class="tab-tooltipContent" wairole="alert" style=""><div class="tab-ubertip tab-widget" style="min-width: 142px;">
  <div class="tab-ubertipCommandArea">

    <div class="tab-ubertipCommands hide"></div>
    <div class="tab-clear"></div><div class="tab-ubertipSelected hide"></div>
  </div><div class="tab-ubertipContent">
    <div class="tab-ubertipTooltip"><span style="white-space:pre-wrap;tab-size:10;-moz-tab-size:10"><div style="text-align:left;"><span style="font-family:'Arial';font-size:13px;color:#000000;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;">Health Group</span></div></span></div>
    <div class="tab-ubertipActions hide"></div>
  </div>

</div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-tooltipConnector"></div>
</div>
```

Step 2:
Once one of the option clicked it will show only one row with its related  value. Say for example , clicked on MG will display MG   16.9% 13.1% 81.6% (full row)and so on and when mousehover it on these values(16.9%, 13.1% etc.) one after another it gives tooltip and that tooltip value I have to fetch.  And code for this as below:

```
<div class = “ tab-tooltip tab-widget tab-tooltipAR”  style=”user-select: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; top: 1px; left:119px;”>… </div>
<div class=”tab-tooltipContainer”>
<div class =”tab-tooltipContent” wairole=”alert” style>
<div class=”tab-ubertip tab-widget” style=”min-width: 368px;”>.
<div class =”tab-ubertipContent”>
<div class=”tab-ubertipTooltip”>
<span style =”white-space:pre-wrap;tab-size:10;-moz-tab-size:10”>
<div style=”text-align:left;”>
                    <span style=””> Castle health Group </span>
</div>
<table style=”vertical-align:top;padding:0px” cellspacing=”0”>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style =”white-space:pre”>
                            <span style=”font-family”>**97**</span>
</td>
<td >
                            <span style=”font-”  >**Minimum**</span>
</td>
```

I am able to fetch the tooltip values(97, Minimum) but how do i mouse hover on each values(16.9%, 13.1% etc) which are just different which each other with 'left' and 'top' attributes.

Please anyone have idea how do i mousehover on each value on the basis of style attribute.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.